# What should I do to get a job in QA? Do companies generally go for fresher as software testing engineer or QA?

Tags: qa-developer, career-development

I am a fresher and just completed my M.TECH COMPUTER

I am very much interested in making my career in QA, I am fundamentally clear about all the testing and methods ..Can i choose it..? As a fresher will a company consider me or not?

And WHAT THINGS should I start learning that can help me in getting a job?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should have any issues being a freshman and getting a job as a QA person. When I first started out I went to my school counselor and got a list of jobs and internships for my career path and decided to go with an automation internship. I got crap for pay, but the experience lead me to the job that I have currently and it's been wonderful. Start learning all you can about the industry and what companies are looking for specifically. A couple of things I would recommend would be ***Agile*** development and ***Automation*** testing (I recommend selenium). These are two great things to start your career with.

Answer (score 2):

I had started  my career as QA trainee. So , If you want to make your career in QA field, then join as trainer or intern and try to get an experience as trainee ,also understand the testing methodologies and technical  how to find  issue and focus on our product /service Quality. Try to familiar with the QA Developer Tools like the Selenium, JUnit etc. After Getting some Experience you can definitely start your career as Testing Engineer.

Answer (score 0):

I took my internship as a sophomore in college while pursing my computer science degree. It was decent money considering and the exp is invaluable. I worked in an agile environment and was the founder of the automated testing framework using C# and Selenium. Employers when searching for QA engineers in school are looking for people who are motivated and have a high level of critical thinking skills not exp otherwise they would hire out of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone about learning Selenium.  Get comfortable with both QA developer tools like Selenium WebDriver, TestNG or JUnit (for Java) or another testing framework for your language of choice, as well as testing methodologies and tools used by manual testers.  If you can't land a job as a QA developer directly, a lot of companies will more readily hire someone who is a mix role between manual and automated testing which is a great door to walk into, especially if they give you room to grow.  In the case of not having a lot of professional experience to prove yourself with, express your desire to learn and improve.  A good employer will recognize that as a long term investment opportunity and will hopefully least at least consider you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get some experience that you can show or talk about. [UTest](http://www.utest.com) is really good for freshers because you can jump in and get paid and develop your skills a bit as part time / contractor and get experience.

Filing bugs with open source projects is good. If you build software start a GitHub account so you can shows people your code examples.